# Why flutter latest verion bug with depedencies

Tags: flutter

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yltc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXAYZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVi6k.png)
Why flutter latest verion bug with depedencies

there are always bug when add new dependency

Comment: Please replace images with text showing you error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.